# C#: wpf adding combobox item to multiple comboboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set multiple combo boxes to all having the same set of values to choose from (from the code side).

```
...
this.startTimeOptions = value;
this.cmbMonday.Items.Clear();
this.cmbTuesday.Items.Clear();

foreach (TimeObject time_option in this.TimeOptions) {
  ComboBoxItem new_item = new ComboBoxItem();
  this.cmbMonday.Items.Add(new_item);
  this.cmbTuesday.Items.Add(new_item);
} 
...
```

Currently when I try setting it I get this error:

"Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one."

So obviously they are complaining about not having a unique parent.  But how do I get around this so that I have multiple comboboxes with the same list:

Comment: Create a new Item for each cbx. They can share their Values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create new ComboBoxItems for each ComboBox. Usually you would use one source collection and [bind it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) to both ComboBoxes, they then will create the new items on their own.